# How to select rows which is not existing

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have used this to select records:

```
SELECT village 
FROM villages 
WHERE type = 'student' 
ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0, 50
```

Then I got this:

```
a, b, c, a, d, e, a, ... x
```

I want the result as:

```
a, b, x, c, e, d, ...
```

Not repeating or exist values.

Pleas suggest me How?

Comment: What do you mean with "not existing"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `DISTINCT`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT village 
FROM villages 
WHERE type='student' 
ORDER BY id DESC 
LIMIT 0, 50
```

Comment: I will get results which is variouse kinds of village. I need result that is not same as other row.

Comment: @Fujael - Yes, this will make each row different from the other row. Each row won't be the same as any other row. Try it.

Comment: Thanks. Just which i need. @ both you.

Answer (score 1):

Use `DISTINCT`  clause in select statement

Answer (score 0):

The other answers already offered DISTINCT which will look at the complete result row and returns them distinct. If you select additional columns and village is not the Primary or a unique key, you can still get one village twice.

In this case you can use GROUP_BY ( village )